# C# color changer on mouseclicks does not work

Tags: c#, winforms

I am try to make a simple color changer on Mouseclicks,  see my code below.

```
MouseButtons _lastButtonUp = MouseButtons.None;

    private void ColorChanger_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0);
        }
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 255);
        }
        _lastButtonUp = e.Button;
    }

    private void ColorChanger_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch (_lastButtonUp)
        {
            case System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left:
                this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0);
                break;
            case System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right:
                this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 0);
                break;
        }
    }
```

However, This only works with single clicks

When I try it without single clicks like this:

```
MouseButtons _lastButtonUp = MouseButtons.None;

    private void ColorChanger_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        _lastButtonUp = e.Button;
    }

    private void ColorChanger_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch (_lastButtonUp)
        {
            case System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left:
                this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0);
                break;
            case System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right:
                this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 0);
                break;
        }
    }
```

the double clicks work.

Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont know what you trying to achieve, but i believe it's because MouseDoubleClick event raises **before** MouseUp event.

For reference of mouse events: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171542(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2

Comment: Nope, MouseUp event raises first.

Comment: @Berkay - the documentation that Andrey's linked to contradicts your assertion. Anything to back it up?

Comment: @Berkay MouseUp rises **two** times: before and after mousedoubleclick

Comment: OP says, "it works with only single clicks". Because before double click MouseUp event fires. @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Comment: So, MouseUp event raises before MouseDoubleClick event. Because between double clicks there have to be a MouseUp. Right?

Comment: MouseDown  -> Click -> MouseClick -> MouseUp -> MouseDown ->
 DoubleClick -> MouseDoubleClick -> MouseUp

Comment: @Berkay - in laborious detail. Start at nothing. The user clicks the mouse button, a full sequence of Down/Up events fires. The user clicks a second time (within the time limit for a double-click). a sequence of Down/Double/Up events fires. The last event to run (and thus the last one to set the colour) is an Up event.